# Make Column scroll item farther into view

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I have an app with a pretty standard TV layout with a list of video shelves. I implemented it as a `TvLazyColumn` with each shelf being a `TvLazyRow` of items. Everything worked fine.

Due to business requirements, I had to change the parent composable to from a `TvLazyColumn` to a regular `Column` (there was a cell that I didn't want getting unloaded). Ever since then, when I scroll down in the parent column, the currently selected item is at the very bottom of the visible part of the column. Is there an easy way to get the `Column` to scroll the currently selected item farther up in the viewport?

I managed the pretty big hack below which just, when a scroll occurs, scroll it a little farther. The downside to that is there's a noticeable stutter when it scrolls, briefly stops, then scrolls again.

```kotlin
    var lastScrollValue by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    // hack to scroll selected row farther into view
    LaunchedEffect(scrollState.value) {
        if (!scrollState.isScrollInProgress && scrollState.value > lastScrollValue) {
            lastScrollValue = scrollState.value + 100
            scrollState.scrollTo(lastScrollValue)
        } else {
            lastScrollValue = scrollState.value
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using a Column is not going to be performant if you have a lot of rows inside it. Are you doing some actions on mount/unmount of the component which is why you had to fallback to using `Column`? If yes, I think it would be better for performance, to hoist boolean flags at a parent level and use those flags to determine if you want to do those actions or not.

Comment: No there was actually a video in the first row that biz wants to keep playing even when scrolled out of view. Performance isn't too bad since there's only 10 shelves.

Comment: I have scrolling long text issue in `TvLazyColumn` would you mind to help if you know how to fix it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76676004/jetpack-compose-tv-is-not-scrollable-and-not-clickable