# Jetpack Compose TV is not scrollable and not clickable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I'm very new to Jetpack Compose for Android TV and don't understand how scrolling and clicking works. For example:

```
 TvLazyColumn(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(24.dp)
                            .fillMaxSize(),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
                    ) {
                        item {
                            Text(
                                modifier = Modifier,
                                text = "very long text here which is need to scroll..."
                            )
                        }
                        item {
                            Button(
                                modifier = Modifier,
                                onClick = {
                                    // handle click event here
                                }) {
                                Text(text = "CLICK ME")
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I'm using Jetpack Compose `tv-foundation` and `tv-material` version **1.0.0-alpha07** and having these issues:

- Clicking a `Button` with a mouse connected to the Android TV device
  never triggers the `onClick` handler, it only works when clicked with the
  remote control.
- Scrolling long text in an `item` of `TvLazyColumn` doesn't work with
  either a mouse or remote control. But changing to `LazyColumn` allows
  scroll with mouse but not remote control.

How can I get reliable scrolling and clicking behavior with both input methods in Jetpack Compose for Android TV? What I missed here?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, pointer and touch input methods are not supported in TvLazyColumn as the component is specifically designed for TV. We are [tracking this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/288121117).

Thanks for this feedback!